# Spawning Sprites in gles2

Tags: android, andengine

below I have code to spawn a sprite every so often and a touch method to get rid of the sprite(it works fine).  My issue is when a zombieSprite2 spawns and I wait for another zombieSprite2 to spawn (so I have two of the same sprite on the screen) when I touch the first zombiesprite2 that spawned it effects the second zombiesprite2 and nothing happens to the first one.  Could it be the touch method only effects the most recently spawned zombiesprite2?

```
this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(
            zombieSpriteTimehandler = new TimerHandler(5, true,
                    new ITimerCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            zombieSprite2 = new Sprite(0, 200,
                                    zombieregion, mEngine
                                            .getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

                                @Override
                                public boolean onAreaTouched(

                                        final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                                        final float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                        final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                                    ScaleModifier sm2 = new ScaleModifier(
                                            5,zombieSprite2.getScaleX(),
                                            zombieSprite2.getScaleX() + 1.03f);

                                    zombieSprite2.registerEntityModifier(sm2);
                                    if (zombieSprite2.getScaleX() > 1.02f) {
                                        zombieSprite2
                                                .setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                        mScene.detachChild(zombieSprite2);
                                        return true;

                                    }

                                    return false;
                                }

                            };

                            mScene.attachChild(zombieSprite2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should declare new object for every spawning sprite.** Here you declare only one sprite object zombieSprite2 on top of the scene & every time it store the last object of the sprite . So you got this effect.

Solution:

```
final Sprite zombieSprite2 = new new Sprite(0, 200,
                                zombieregion, mEngine
                                        .getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onAreaTouched(

                                    final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                                    final float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                    final float pTouchAreaLocalY) { // do your works here}
```

Comment: reply it you saw this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, when I put final Sprite zombieSprite2 there is an error in my ontouch method saying local variable zombieSprite2 may not have been initialized.  Before I just made a public Sprite zombieSprite2 variable, but that was part of the problem. Sorry for taking so long to reply.

Comment: you have to remove first class level declaration for  zombieSprite2. happy, it works for you...stay close